# how to code it to get pass error in method

Tags: java, arrays, string

Basically i am trying to build a calculator that will allow the user to choose `1-5` for the options of multiplying, subtracting, multiplying, or dividing. from whatever they choose, i will then ask them to enter `2` numbers after selecting which function they want. i am trying to put this bit into the calculation bit below but i am running into this error here, not sure how it should be formatted. At this part of the code i am receiving the error.

```
inputOperation = mySelection.selectionOne().equals("5"); //this is where I a getting the error "cannot convert boolean to int"
```

The part i am trying to insert in the below code is (I think):

```
public class Selection {
    Scanner readInput = new Scanner(System.in);



String selectionOne() {
    String input;
    do { //do loop will continue to run until user enters correct response
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 5, A for Addition, S for Subtraction, M for Multiplication, or D for Division, or X for Exit: ");
        try { 
            input = readInput.nextLine(); //user will enter a response
            if (input.equals("A") || input.equals("S") || input.equals("M") || input.equals("D") || input.equals("X")) {
                System.out.println("Thank you");
                break; //user entered a character of A, S, M, or D
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(input) >= 1 && Integer.parseInt(input) <= 5) { 
                System.out.println("Thank you");
                break; //user entered a number between 1 and 5
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you have not entered the correct number, please try again.");
            }
            continue;
        }
        catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice. Try again.");
            continue; // loop will continue until correct answer is found
        }
    } while (true);
    return input;
}
```

.

```
public class answers {

public float answer(int choice, float [] f){
    float result = 0.00f;

    switch (choice){
    case 1: result = f[0]+f[1]; break;
    case 2: result = f[0]-f[1]; break;
    case 3: result = f[0]*f[1]; break;
    case 4: result = f[0]/f[1]; break;
    case 5: System.out.println("You are now exting the program \n"); break;
    default: System.out.println("Cannot calculate.\n You entered" + choice); break;

    }
    return result;
}

public static void main (String args[]){
    int inputOperation;
    Selection mySelection = new Selection();

    inputOperation = mySelection.selectionOne().equals("5"); //this is where I a getting the error "cannot convert boolean to int"
    Symbol.newSymbol("You entered a choice of " + inputOperation + " successfully\n\n");
    Symbol.displaySymbol();
    float [] myFloats = mySelection.pickNumbers(inputOperation);
    Symbol.newSymbol("You entered " + myFloats[0] + " and " + myFloats[1] + " successfully\n\n") ;
    Symbol.displaySymbol();
}
}
```

Comment: boolean equals(Object anObject)
Compares this string to the specified object.

Comment: The result of equals method is boolean

Answer (score 0):

.equals("") method will return boolean value.

You are trying to store a boolean value in a int variable (inputOperation).

Answer (score 0):

equals method signature is :

> boolean   equals(Object anObject)
>     Compares this string to the specified object.

[refer java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

when `mySelection.selectionOne().equals("5");`  execute it will return boolean value.